# File disappears from Finder when hard link copy is deleted

Tags: macos, finder, hardlink

Ok, I just got quite the scare... I have a folder with some important files. Using the Terminal I had created hard-links to those files in a different folder. Something like this:

```
mkdir test
ln important-files/* test/
```

All well and good. I had a Finder window open in the `important-files` folder, and in the Terminal I then decided to delete my test folder with the hard-links:

```
rm -rf test/
```

Now comes the scary part... in the `important-files` Finder window , the files started to disappear!

Turns out it was just Mac OS X being "funny" like it often is. The files were still there if I did an `ls important-files/`. But the only way to get them back in the Finder was to do a `killall Finder`.

What in the world is going on here? Why is it doing this?

**Update:** Is this a bug in Mac OS X 10.4 or something? I seem to get less scary behavior on an iMac with 10.5 here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OS X filesystem event API uses paths in the callback, so this must be Finder being stupid and resolving to inodes for its internal cache. A path linked to a specific inode disappears, so all entries linked to that inode disappear.

Comment: That is probably the reason. Annoying stuff... Guess they fixed it in 10.5

Comment: Or at least I hope so...